# Aurelia: Deriving a component from another and reusing HTML

Tags: aurelia

In Aurelia, how do I derive a component from another component reusing the HTML view from the source component?

I have a component `BarGraph` that renders simple bar graphs. This component has files `bar-graph.js` and `bar-graph.html`. I want to derive a set of components from `BarGraph`. Each `*BarGraph` class will have custom logic, but all of the derived components will have the same HTML as the original component. I want to store the HTML for the components in one file and reuse it in each `*BarGraph` class.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `@useView`. For example:

```
import {useView} from 'aurelia-framework';

@useView('./bar-graph.html')
export class AnotherBarGraph {
  // Your logic here
}
```

Documentation [here](http://aurelia.io/docs.html#/aurelia/framework/1.0.0-beta.1.2.2/doc/article/cheat-sheet/2)

EDIT: Extending custom element using inheritance is currently not supported. An important point is "Inheritance of Bindables doesn't work". See this [issue](https://github.com/aurelia/framework/issues/210).

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something but I don't see in this case it's using inheritance, it's just reusing a view with different logic?

Comment: @MattMcCabe Yes, it's just reusing view. Custom element inheritance is not supported yet.